# How to show News & Events in wordpress by plugin

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins

Good After noon all,
         first of all sorry if you think that its wrong way to ask a qustion or i asked a damn low level question but sorry as m new for wordpress and m not familier with plugins..so my problems is that i want to use a plugin by which i can show News & events in my page..

till now i have used this plugin

http://wordpress.org/plugins/press-news-events/

and its my 6th plugin which m using so dont think that m expert with plugins and all..
i tried to change the plugin bt then i created new post for events and news but i dnt know how to show those on my page with down to up movements..sorry if i ask in wrong way bt m trying from last 2 days still din get anything else then that plugin and yup i read the post about events and news on this forum but they are without plugin but i want a way to use that right plugin..thanx... if you can help..plz dont give negative marks..plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the plugin on this url for news and events-

```
http://www.studiostacks.com/plugins/simple-events-calendar/
```